# SignalR GetHubContext not working

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to connect to My SignalR project from another project using GetHubContext but it just wont work. here's the code:

first project

```
[HubName("DataHub")]
public class DataHub : Hub
{
    int counter = 1;

    public void Hello(String message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }

    public void getNewData(Dictionary<string,string> s)
    {


        Object result = new[] { s };
            Clients.All.addnothing(result);       

    }
```

Second project:

```
class Class1
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Tape.DataHub>();
        while(true){
     Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string> { };
        data.Add("User", "PD");
        data.Add("DeviceId","445");
        data.Add("ID", "1"); 

        Object result = new[] { data };

        hubContext.Clients.All.addData(data);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }



    }
}
```

}

Javascript code for the client

```
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:57844/signalr";
var dataHub = $.connection.DataHub;


dataHub.client.addData = function (message) {
    console.log(message);

    var obj = message;

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
         //loops through the data and adds new data to the html page
 }



    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        console.log("connected");
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log('Invocation of start failed. Error: ' + error)
    });
```

The client should get new Data from class1 through signalr hub that is on a different class than the signalr project. But Im not getting any new data, the client only connects to DataHub. Is there something missing?

Comment: Are you self hosting from second project? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: No I am not self hosting

Comment: But the project that is doing GetHubContext seems to be a Console app? You can offcouse only do GetHubContext from the same Appdomain that is hosting the signalr service

Comment: Yes its a console app but on a different project, not on the same project that is hosting signalr. Can it be on a different project? I did reference it though. I referenced the project and the class :
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Tape.DataHub>();

Comment: They can be in different projects but they need to be hosted under the same app domain (Same process). If they are not you can use a service bus to communicate between the applications. Like http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-service-bus

Comment: How can I  give the two projects same app domain on visual studio? I'm sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: You have a console project and a web project hosting signalR, correct? These two will run under totaly different scopes (seperate process, seperate app domain). You can only call GetHubContext from the web project, but the code that does it can be in a seperate project (Assemly) but it cant be in a sperate process / app domain.

Comment: Okay thank you :) , can u put that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a console project and a web project hosting signalR, correct? 
These two will run under totaly different scopes (seperate process, seperate app domain). You can only call `GetHubContext` from the web project, but the code that does it can be in a seperate project (Assemly) but it cant be in a sperate process / app domain.

If you need the code that does `GetHubContext` in a seperate process for some reason you need to use soem kind of integration like a servicebus, WCF etc